# Unity 2018.2.17 with SQLite: MonoBleedingEdge error?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sqlite, system.data

I have used SQLite on my Unity game without problems until now: today I was prompted with an update for Unity (to 2018.2.17), and after updating I can't build anymore my games.

There is now a conflict between my project's System.Data.DLL and another one found in a MonoBleedingEdge subfolder.

The one on my project was copied from: Unity/Contents/Mono/lib/mono/unity/System.Data.DLL

And the MonoBleedingEdge folder is: Unity/Contents/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/System.Data.DLL

The file sizes are completely different (mono is ~700-800kb and MonoBleedingEdge is ~200kb).

Any ideas on how to fix, or why this happened? Or why it happened only now?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem in several unity windows standalone projects with 2018.2.17 and 2018.2.18

i deleted a System.Data.dll in the folder Assets/Plugins/SQLite/ in my project. that solved it for me.